# difference between fine and very well?

Tags: word-usage, greetings

I learnt that one of this is officially accepted, is there any difference between **I am fine, thank you**,  and **I am very well, thank you** ?.

I was preparing for an interview, and a friend of mine interviewed me just to be sure I'd prepared enough for the interview. The pre-interviewed question was below.

> Friend: Hi, how are you?
>
> Response: I'm fine, thank you.

He said in most context,  it is better to say **I'm very well, thank you**.

Comment: "Officially"? English, unlike some languages, has no official rules and no officialdom to attempt to police them.

Comment: Interesting. Never have thought to pay serious attention to this.

Answer (score 2):

The **I'm fine** response is neutral. It's a way of saying "nothing is wrong" in a positive statement. By giving this response you indicate that nothing out of the ordinary is going on, it's essentially a generic but polite response to a generic, polite greeting.

However the **I am very well** response is much more positive. There's no real reason you couldn't use it, but most people tend to use the neutral response.

I can't really say why English speakers prefer a neutral response to a positive one, there might be some interesting implications there, but that's just how it is.

Comment: I think that there must be regional, social, cultural variations. Most people I know say 'I am very well' whether they are or not. If one of them says 'I'm fine' I would look concerned and ask gently what was wrong.